# SQL Server 2000 job failure from DTS package versions?

Tags: sql-server, dts

I've been having a reoccurring problem that escapes me at this point.  I have a job set up in SQL Server 2k that has a few command steps which are followed up by 4 steps that just call DTS packages on the same server.  When it comes to calling the packages, the job fails with no real reason given.  Ok fine...

Well the thing that I can't figure out is that if I run the packages in order separately they work 100% of the time.  I've deleted the packages entirely and re-added them as well as modifying the corresponding step.  Am I missing something?

Is there something inherit with the DTS package versioning that causes the job to fail when the package runs just fine as a standalone?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've always had issues with DTS packages on our SQL Server 2000 databases.  You could try checking the windows event viewer/system error logs to see if there is anything more detailed in there.

We've had credentialing issues before that jobs would fail because the windows account running the job may have become inactive - so maybe the credentials the first job is running under doesn't have access to run dts packages, but you (as an administrator) do ?

Comment: You were close and your reply helped me thing about the user credentials.  In the end the problem was that for some reason the packages kept losing the logon credentials I was setting.  In the end they were running as "me" from the domain, and the jobs were passing in a user/pwd which failed the package.  Odd, but I did catch that and set up everything again which thus far has worked out.  It feels like a Microsoft house of cards, but what can you do I guess.

Thanks.